# Am I using mocks the right way?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have some legacy stuff and want to cover it by tests.
There is following method which I don't know how to test using mocks.

```
public String listTransactions(Request request, Response response) {
    String transactionFamily = request.get("transactionFamily");
    List transactions = service.fetchTransactions(transactionFamily);
    responseBuilder.addElement("collection", transactions);
    responseBuilder.addElement("token", tokenGenerator.next());
    String  formattedResponse = responseBuilder.build();
    response.send(formattedResponse);
    return null;
}
```

My first approach was:

```
public void testResponseIsBuilt() {
    request = stub(Request.class);
    request.method("get").with("transactionFamily").willReturn("dummyFamily");
    response = mock(Response.class);
    response.mehod("send").called(once());
    service = stub(TransactionService.class);
    service.method("fetchTransactions").willReturn(testTransactions);
    responseBuilder = mock(ResponseBuilder.class);
    responseBuilder.method("addElement").called(once()).with("collection", testTransactions);
    responseBuilder.method("addElement").called(once()).with("token", sampleToken);
    responseBuilder.method("build").called(once());     
    responder.setService(service);
    responder.setResponseBuilder(responseBuilder);

    responder.listTransactions(request, response);
}
```

I know single test case should cover only single aspect of SUT. So taking this into account I can imagine following set of tests:

- testTransactionsFetchedForFamily
- testTransactionsAddedToResponse
- testTokenSetInResponse
- testFormattedResponseBuilt
- testResponseSent

E.g. to execute "testResponseBuilt" I need to do setup like this (as above)

- stub request
- stub service
- mock responseBuilder with 3 expects (2 addElement and 1 build)

Isn't it too much there? Isn't such setup too complicated? Do I "overmock" here?

I can think of putting all that responseBuilder things into separate collaborator, but it's getting a bit crazy for me as I've just extracted ResponseBuilder itself.

I suspect that I miss some important points in writing unit tests here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going a bit too far with those tests. It seems your method's responsibility is to correctly set up and send response (judging from code - naming could be better, as in, what *transactions* is it *listing* now?). And that's what should be tested here.

**Edit:**

On a second look, it seems that majority of work is done by `responseBuilder` - remaining code just sets it up. So what you really could test here is whether it is provided with expected data (that's one or two tests) and finally whether response is sent (second/third test). Note that checking whether `.build` is called is not that necessary, as its absence would fail response sending test.

This means you'll need to mock and verify expectations on `responseBuilder` (`.add` method) and `response` (`.send`). Testing response format belongs to `responseBuilder` test, just as testing whether transactions are fetched correctly belongs to `service` tests.

*(You could also possibly verify that `service` is called with correct parameter as it's hardcoded, but that's only if you want to be super-cautious)*

Overall, I would strike out tests #1 and #4 and focus on remaining ones.

And in order to verify those expectations, you'll have to stub out remaining dependencies. There's no real way around that. You need to find the sweet-spot between deciding how much code are you willing to write in order to test single line of code (and whether it is worth it).

Comment: But to set up some mock expectations I need to reveal some internals in my tests, right? And to get correct response format I need to prepare responseBuilder to be feed up with transactions and token, so I need to reveal internals again. Or am I completely lost here?

Comment: @grafthez: check my edit - you are parially right, what you want to test is whether responseBuilder is fed with correct data and whether response is sent. Other tests belong to different classes.

Answer (score 1):

The test suite should contain the setup method where request, service should be mentioned. This would make sure you reuse the variables for all your test cases. The more modular you make the more fine grained response you get. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sure you're right. I've made it clear here - it'd go to setUp() in real implementation. My problem is a bit different: my implementation does "a b c d" and to test "b" expectation a need to setup "a". To test "c" expectation I need to setup "a b", and so on...

Comment: JUnit are to test a flow, so as I understand you need to test for d for the complete test case and give asserts for c,b and a. Your test suite should contain only one test which will test the flow.